# How to set a function as a default value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, default

I am in trouble please help.

After searching for my question I decided to post here.

Look at my code below and tell me if I can set default value as a function.

What I want to do is to show first three characters of my first column's data which is `Product_Name`.

For example my first column has a name `Xperia` and and I want its first three characters to be shown in the last column which I have created using alter code.

I hope you understand what I say.

```
Xperia ---->  Xpe
```

Code is :

```
alter table dummy
add new_col varchar(250) default substring(first_column, 1, 3)
```

returns an error:

> Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   The name "first_column" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

However I can set `getdate()` function as a default value.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your question. You say "How ever i can set getdate() function as a default value" but I cannot see how that relates to adding a field based on `Product_Name`?

Comment: oh that was an example of setting a function as a default value.. it has nothing to do with this code.. sorry if you misled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to alter the table? It sounds like you need a `VIEW`.

A view can add an additional field, selecting only the first three characters, and would not need to be updated each time you `UPDATE` or `INSERT` data. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW Table_With_Truncated_Product_Name
AS
SELECT *, LEFT(Product_Name, 3) AS truncated_product_name
FROM Your_Table
```

However, if you don't want to use a `VIEW` it may be possible to use a [Computed Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx).

In which case you would alter your table and add the field:

```
ALTER TABLE Your_Table ADD truncated_product_name AS LEFT(Product_Name, 3)
```

Although I don't have access to SQL Server at the moment to check that would work.

Comment: I could execute it successfully but i dont see any column in the end showing three characters from my first column

Comment: You would now need to `SELECT` from the view, not the original table.

Comment: ahh one problem, if i remove any column then the view doesnt works.. :(

Comment: Ok as soon as my pc gets better I will try what you said in the edited statement..

Comment: your edited statement worked like a charm. Thumbs up